# Slowly change a value with javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, increment

I'm making a prototype of an interface for boats. Details aside, I have created a numpad using javascript onClick that lets you input a value and then send that value to another field, let's call it "current". Is there a way to make the "current" field I'm sending to slowly increase until it reaches the value i send from my numpad?

For example, if I enter the number 24 on my numpad and click "submit", the "current" field shows 24 right away, but I would like for it to slowly tick up to 24 in increments. This might sound like a silly detail but it would make quite a difference for my prototype.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make a separate variable called currentMax. When the user clicks submit, currentMax is set to the number they input (let's say 24). current, the visible variable, will then increment until it reaches currentMax. So it's gonna look something like this: `if(currentMax > current){current++}`. Keep in mind that currentMax should not be visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use javascript's setInterval function:

```
var handle;

function func() {
    // Increment the value by 1
    if(necessary value is reached) {
        window.clearInterval(handle);
    }
}

handle = window.setInterval("func", 50); // Run each 50ms
```

Comment: This seems to be able to do it, but where exactly does it tell the script to repeat the action every 50 ms? Shouldn't I call in the "handle" somewhere in my function? I'm asking cause I can't get it to work... Even if I comment out the if statement it still only increments 1 every time i click the button. (button has onclick="func()")